# DLL load failed while importing 'matplotlib' in a virtual environment

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda, python-venv

I've created a virtual environment to handle my script dependeciens on libraries' versions. I then installed all needed libraries at the latest versions in the virtual environment. The scripts involved are `numpy`, `scipy`, `pandas` (used by a user-called module), and `matplotlib`.

However, my script `qmc_sobol.py`, which I attached, runs well with the Python 3.11.4 ('base') from Conda, while I get the below error when I launch the file in the virtual environment, named `venv_sobol_sensitivity`.

I attach a link to a dropbox shared folder with the error screenshot and the python scripts:
[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/3fvv2tw3ghu4xjy3wajhn/h?rlkey=5ato0t96sks67d1sn1oj3snnf&dl=0)

I use VS Code to write my Python script on a virtual machine with Windows 11, on macOS 14.2.1.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents\SALib_application\qmc_sobol.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Documents\SALib_application\venv_sobol_sensitivity\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 272, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Documents\SALib_application\venv_sobol_sensitivity\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 266, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:Documents\SALib_application\venv_sobol_sensitivity\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried to launch a Python script which uses `numpy`, `scipy`, `matplotlib`, and `pandas` in a dedicated virtual environment. Although I installed all the libraries in the virtual environment, I get an error that says `matplotlib module could not be found`

Comment: Thanks @merv for your help! However, sorry for my naivess, but what does "would indicate that a system-level Python is leaking into your environment." mean, please?

Comment: I see now this is the behavior with `venv` environment, not a Conda one. Since `venv` is part of Python default modules, it probably isn't the issue. I.e., in Conda seeing something loading from outside the environment directory is weird, but for `venv` environments it could be fine. Removing my previous remark.